# How to validate commutativity involving the dif/2 constraint?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif, clp

There is a lot of hype around the dif/2 constraint, especially as a rescue for some non-declarativity of (\=)/2 and (\==)/2. This non-declarativity is often characterized as non-monotonicity and examples of non-communtativity are given.

But what would be the means to test whether test cases involving dif/2 are commutative. Here is a meta explanation what I want to do:

> I make a commutativity test, and I want to probe that both variants
>   give the same result:
>
> ```
> ?- A, B.
> -- versus --
> ?- B, A.
> ```

So usually you can check monotonicity, if it boils down to checking commutativity, with the (==)/2 built-in predicate. Since this predicate follows instantiated variables.

But if you are testing cases that produce constraints, call_with_residue/2
is not enough, you need also to have equality of constraints. Which can
be tricky, as the following example shows:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.3.23)
Copyright (c) 1990-2015 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam

?- dif(f(X,X),f(a(U,g(T)),a(g(Z),U))), X=a(g(Z),U).
X = a(g(Z), U),
dif(f(a(g(Z), U), U, Z, U, T), f(a(U, g(T)), g(Z), T, g(Z), Z)).

?- X=a(g(Z),U), dif(f(X,X),f(a(U,g(T)),a(g(Z),U))).
X = a(g(Z), U),
dif(f(U, T), f(g(Z), Z)).
```

Any ideas how to proceed?

**Disclaimer, its a trap:**
I don't endorse commutativity testing as a good testing method, where you can separate good and bad predicates versus a specification. Since usually both the good and bad predicates might have no problems with commutativity.

I am using commutativity testing as a vehicle to find out about methods for equality of dif/2 constraints. This equality can then be used in more traditional test cases as a validation point.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways. Maybe the easiest in this case is to simply re-post the collected residual constraints.

In this example, we get:

```
?- X = a(g(Z), U),
   dif(f(a(g(Z), U), U, Z, U, T), f(a(U, g(T)), g(Z), T, g(Z), Z)).
X = a(g(Z), U),
dif(f(U, T), f(g(Z), Z)).
```

The goal is now much simpler!

You can collect residual goals with `copy_term/3` and  `call_residue_vars/2`.

Comment: But can I also automate a repost with call_residue_vars/2. I didn't try. And this is probably only half of the bill. If they are simpler, can you compare the constraints in some way? (The simpler ones need not look equal)